# Mongoose - is it possible to overwrite findOneAndUpdate options 'new' flag as true in schema level?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, findoneandupdate

Currently, I can add `new: true` flag in options in each and every `findOneAndUpdate` query to get updated document, but would like to know if there is an option to overwrite this on global level, so I dont need to add this flag in every `findOneAndUpdate` query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mongoose.set()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-set)

```
mongoose.set('returnOriginal',false);
```

**From the docs :** This is equivalent to setting the new option to true for findOneAndX() calls by default.
For schema : `schema.set('returnOriginal',false)`. [Docs link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-set)